# Accidentally changed the permissons of .ssh and now cannot access ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, public-key-encryption, pem

I accidentally changed the permissions of .ssh directory and everything inside of it to 777 in my ec2 instance as ec2-user (root) and logged out of the instance. Now I cannot ssh into my instance since the permissions are too open. Is there anything I can do without creating a new instance? I have access to other users in the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got another user with SSH access to the instance you can log in using that user account.

Note if the permissions issue only affects the `ec2-user` account, you can log in with the other user and should be able to fix the permissions.

Also note you can use the [EC2 Serial Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-serial-console.html) to troubleshoot issues with your instance, even if you can't SSH into it.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you try to use AWS Systems Manager (SSM) to access the instance
  and fix the permissions
- Try detaching the root EBS volume from this instance and attaching it to another instance as a secondary volume. You could then correct the permissions directly from the other instance.
- if you have another user with sudo
  privileges, login with that user - let's say ec2-user and do the
  below steps
  these should help

  ```
   sudo su

   chmod 700 /home/ec2-user/.ssh #     Fix permissions

   chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/*
   chmod 644 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/*.pub
  ```